Seasoning statistics of a metric
By *seasoning" I mean a metric that fluctuates near periodically, e.g. number of players reaches its peak at Saturday and Sunday.
Suppose I have a matric my_metric with period of one week. How to calculate the mean of its values at the same time of the previous 3 weeks (mathematically, v[n-1w] + v[n-2w] + v[n-3w])?
I tried

avg_over_time({my_metric}[3w:1w]), but its sample rate becomes 1 week, while I need it to be more meaningful for monitoring, e.g. 5m or 10m.

sum(agv_over_time(my_metric[1w] offset 1w)) (and the offset 2w and 3w) is the average within a consecutive week, not the same points of 3 weeks.



I think you mean "seasonal", not "seasoning", but in the context of your description I don't think that is really appropriate though, as seasonal generally refers to the season (or at least periods of time that correspond roughly to the seasons (winter, spring, summer, autumn)). For example, seasonal work in a popular vacation destination peaks in - for example - the summer, and dips in winter.

Is (my_metric offset 1w + my_metric offset 2w + my_metric offset 3w) / 3 what you want?

Add three values and divided by 3 works for mean, but I need more statistics, e.g medium,stddev.
